# tcp_probe function not implemented

Tags: drivers, tcp-ip

Good day!
I was trying to load the module "tcp_probe" when I got the following error    "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tcp_probe': Function not implemented"
for reference, my kernel is 4.15.7 and tcp_probe module is enabled in the configuration of the kernel.

The command that I used was

> sudo modprobe tcp_probe port=5001

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory.  The function you're trying to load up isn't implemented in whatever the kernel version you're on is.  What Ubuntu are you on, anyways?  4.15.7 is very very "new" compared to the kernels that're in the existing releases.

Comment: @ThomasWard 16.04, any idea on which latest version has this function enabled?

Comment: I just tested on the HWE kernel which is 4.13.x and it didn't have any issues.  But, your kernel is newer than the kernels in the repository for Xenial (latest is 4.13.x, and that's if you track the HWE kernel).  Are you using a non-standard kernel, or a mainline PPA based kernel, or a custom kernel, by chance?

Comment: @ThomasWard not really, I am using a standardized kernel. Thank you for your reply. I will compile an older version. I was just wondering why that'd happen when the module is enabled.

Comment: Define 'standardized'.  Where did you get the kernel from?  Mainline Kernel PPA?  Did you compile it from upstream (this is still a 'custom' kernel because it's not from the repos)?  Was it provided by another party?  Try installing `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` which has the 4.13.0 kernel, and see if it works there.

Comment: It seems to be in some kernels and not others. It is in mainline 4.15.7 (`/lib/modules/4.15.7-041507-generic/kernel/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.ko`) What is the kernel config swtich name? I haven't been able to find it yet. I guess `CONFIG_NET_TCPPROBE`. Hmmm... gone in kernel 4.16rc series.

Comment: I get the same error as you, even though the module is there. Now it has been removed from the kernel, and I just think that its removal got out of sync with the removal of some required infrastructure. See [also](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10124949/).